# NodeJS - using "--trace-sync-io" getting "WARNING: Detected use of sync API"

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Background**: Im trying to create a small test of a fully async node js demo.
Then i can see what a good sample looks like in order to cleanup some other project i have done.

heres my code

```js
//https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c
function doubleAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x * 2);
    }, 500);
  });
}

function addPromise(x){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    doubleAfter2Seconds(10).then((a) => {
      doubleAfter2Seconds(20).then((b) => {
        doubleAfter2Seconds(30).then((c) => {
          resolve(x + a + b + c);
       })
      })
    })
  });
}

addPromise(10).then((sum) => {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

The first (of many!) warning i get is this in the Node Debug Console.

```
Debugger attached.
(node:29884) WARNING: Detected use of sync API

at realpathSync (fs.js:1437:13)
at toRealPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:205:13)
at Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:287:22)
at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:25)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
at Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
```

**My questions are:** -

1. what does this mean? **Detected use of sync API**
2. Is my Demo not **fully** async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What does this mean? **Detected use of sync API**

`trace-sync-io` detects calls to the Node sync APIs, like `fs.readFileSync`. So these warnings are what you are trying to catch

In order to execute your code, Node has to load your file synchronously. The same thing happens when you `require` a file. So it is expected that you have lots of warning like this:

`(node:29884) WARNING: Detected use of sync API at realpathSync (fs.js:1437:13)`

You can try it with an empty file and you will see the same warnings: `node --trace-sync-io empty-file.js`

> 2. Is my Demo not **fully** async?

Your Demo is *fully async* regarding that it does not call any sync API

Comment: Thank you Juan, i think im looking for the wrong thing, Im trying to find blocking code, is --trace-sync-io the best solution for this?

Comment: You may use a library such as [blocked-at](https://github.com/naugtur/blocked-at). In that case, you should wrap your function call inside a `setImmediate`, like this: `setImmediate(() => addPromise(10).then(console.log));`